# AWS Custom CloudWatch metrics - Aggregate by Auto-Scaling group

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to set some custom AWS CloudWatch metrics using the Java SDK.

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation describing how to get certain pieces of data, nor what data I need to include.

```
MetricDatum datum = new MetricDatum()
    .withDimensions(
        new Dimension()
            .withName("InstanceType").withValue(/* 1 */),
        new Dimension()
            .withName("InstanceId").withValue(/* 2 */)
        /* 3 */
    .withMetricName("My metric").withTimestamp(new Date())
    .withUnit("Percent").withValue(new Double(55.0));
```

So, questions (for each of the commented numbers in the code above):

1. Where do I get the data to put here, using the Java AWS SDK?
2. Where do I get the data to put here, using the Java AWS SDK?
3. What other data do I need to include in order to ensure I can aggregate by auto-scaling group?
   (aggregating by security group would also be fine)

For #1, I've seen that I can make a regular HTTP call to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id to get the instance-id, but I'm hoping to do this all via the AWS SDK, if there are methods available to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I posted the question to the Amazon support team.

The [EC2 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html) gives a list of URLs that can be called to grab a bunch of meta-data, including the InstanceType (question 1), the InstanceId (question 2), and the security group (question 3).

The auto-scaling group can be obtained using the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/), by getting a list of all the auto-scaling groups, and then iterating through that list until you find the instance with your own instanceId (that was retrieved using the URL listed above):

```
String instanceId = "Your-InstanceId";
AmazonAutoScalingClient amazonAutoScalingClient = new AmazonAutoScalingClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
DescribeAutoScalingGroupsResult describeAutoScalingGroupsResult = amazonAutoScalingClient.describeAutoScalingGroups();
for(AutoScalingGroup autoScalingGroup : describeAutoScalingGroupsResult.getAutoScalingGroups()) {
    for(Instance instance : autoScalingGroup.getInstances()) {
        if(instance.getInstanceId().equals(instanceId)) {
            return autoScalingGroup.getAutoScalingGroupName();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not in the javadocs, but there's a handy utility class called [EC2MetadataUtils](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/1.9.31/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/util/EC2MetadataUtils.java) that'll give you metadata info such as InstanceType (1) and InstanceId (2).

As far as getting the ASG name, AWS [documents](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/ASTagging.html) that

> when you launch an instance in an Auto Scaling group, Auto Scaling adds a tag to the instance with a key of aws:autoscaling:groupName and a value of the name of the Auto Scaling group

So you can save a little looping by just fetching the tags for the instance

```
String instanceId = EC2MetadataUtils.getInstanceId();

String asgName = null;
List<TagDescription> tagDescriptions = new AmazonEC2Client().describeTags(
        new DescribeTagsRequest().withFilters(
            new Filter().withName("resource-id").withValues(instanceId)
        )
).getTags();
for (TagDescription tagDescription : tagDescriptions) {
    if ("aws:autoscaling:groupName".equals(tagDescription.getKey())) {
        asgName = tagDescription.getValue();
        break;
    }
}
```

The Dimension name you would use to ensure you can aggregate by Auto Scaling Group Name is `AutoScalingGroupName` (3)

```
new Dimension().withName("AutoScalingGroupName").withValue(asgName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to implement this same thing with version 1.10.17 of the AWS Java SDK, and the solution provided by @Tinclon in the accepted answer only returns null for the auto scaling group. The following snippet, however, did correctly return the auto scaling group for me.

```
    String getAutoscalingGroup(final String instanceId) {
    final DescribeAutoScalingInstancesRequest describeRequest = new DescribeAutoScalingInstancesRequest().withInstanceIds(Collections.singleton(instanceId));
    final DescribeAutoScalingInstancesResult result = autoScalingClient.describeAutoScalingInstances(describeRequest);

    for (AutoScalingInstanceDetails details : result.getAutoScalingInstances()) {
        if (StringUtils.equals(instanceId, details.getInstanceId())) {
            return details.getAutoScalingGroupName();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

I didn't try this with other versions of the SDK, but the [functionality is equivalent](https://serverfault.com/a/654856/84276) with the functionality in the (as of today) latest version of the AWS command line client

Answer (score -1):

You can aggregate by image id:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/ami-id
```

Typically, an auto-scale group runs on a dedicated image, so this approach should work.